# Converting string to particular datetime format

Tags: ruby

I want to convert 2 dates

`"05/14/2020"` to 05-14-2020 00:00:00. (start of the day)

`"05/31/2020"` to 05-31-2020 23:59:59. (end of the day)

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Time.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) to parse a string that's composed of your date string and a fixed time value:

```
require 'time'

from = '05/14/2020'
to = '05/31/2020'

Time.strptime("#{from} 00:00:00", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
#=> 2020-05-14 00:00:00 +0200

Time.strptime("#{to} 23:59:59", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
#=> 2020-05-31 23:59:59 +0200
```

Comment: HI Stefan, Your `slice_before` suggestion to my question perfectly worked for me. Since my question got downvoted, I deleted it. Thanks your solution resolved my problem. I will delete this comment once after you have seen it.

Comment: @Rajagopalan you're welcome. But don't delete questions just because you got a downvote. People spent time reading it and providing help (via comments and answers). Deleting the question invalidates their efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
Date.strptime("05/14/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").beginning_of_day
#=> Thu, 14 May 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00

Date.strptime("05/31/2020", "%m/%d/%Y").end_of_day
#=> Sun, 31 May 2020 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: I am getting error for both.                                                                                  
 NoMethodError (undefined method `beginning_of_day' for #<Date: 2020-05-14 ((2458984j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>)

Comment: Use `DateTime.strptime` instead of Date

Comment: @Mahant [`Date#beginning_of_day`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) is a Rails method (your question has the `ruby-on-rails` tag)

Comment: @Stefan I did not see any rails tag individually

Comment: @Mahant tags categorize questions. Your question has two tags: `ruby-on-rails` and `ruby`. Therefore, we assume that your question is about Ruby on Rails. If your question isn't related to Rails, you should remove that tag (there's an _edit_ button).

Comment: @Mahant Then you have to tag only "ruby". Well, you can install the gem `activesupport` (which is part of the Rails framework) and `require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'`, then you have the method `beginning_of_day`.